# Siddhi query for network utilization

Tags: wso2, siddhi

I am currently evaluating [siddhi](http://wso2.com/products/complex-event-processor/) for use in a snmp environment. The POC is build around network interface utilization.

A stream is defined as:

```
define stream interfaceStatsEvents (nodeName string, sdate double, ifSpeed long, ifIndex string, ifAdminStatus string, ifOperStatus string,
ifInDiscards long, ifInErrors long, ifOutDiscards long, ifOutErrors long, ifInOctets long, ifOutOctets long)
```

The query for calculating interface utilization as:

```
from every (e1 = interfaceStatsEvents -> e2 = interfaceStatsEvents[nodeName == e1.nodeName and ifIndex == e1.ifIndex]) 
select e1.nodeName, e1.ifIndex, ((e2.ifInOctets - e1.ifInOctets) * 8 * 100) / (((e2.sdate - e1.sdate) / 1000) * e1.ifSpeed) as utilization 
insert into interfaceUtilization;
```

The problem is that the query seems to run only once. **4** events were added to the  *interfaceStatsEvents* stream. Was expecting 3 events to be generated for *interfaceUtilization*, instead only a single event was generated.

Does anyone have an idea on the reason for that or how to fix the query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue here is you are using every for the whole pattern, hence this will output for every e1,e2 combination

```
from every (e1 = interfaceStatsEvents -> e2 = interfaceStatsEvents[nodeName == e1.nodeName and ifIndex == e1.ifIndex])
```

to get an output as you expected i.e for every e1 followed by e2 you have to change the query as

```
from every e1 = interfaceStatsEvents -> e2 = interfaceStatsEvents[nodeName == e1.nodeName and ifIndex == e1.ifIndex]
```

here the every will only apply for e1 and not for e1-e2 combination.